# Identity for multiple variables minimization

Tags: inequality, optimization, maxima-minima

I would like the prove the following identity:

$$\min\limits_{\mathbf{x},\mathbf{y}}[f(\mathbf{x})+g(\mathbf{y})]=\min\limits_{\mathbf{x}}[f(\mathbf{x})]+\min\limits_{\mathbf{y}}[g(\mathbf{y})]$$

At first, I supposed that this should be an inequality, because I tried proving this by doing:

\begin{align}
\min\limits_{\mathbf{x},\mathbf{y}}[f(\mathbf{x})+g(\mathbf{y})]\geq \min\limits_{\mathbf{x},\mathbf{y}}[f(\mathbf{x})]+\min\limits_{\mathbf{x},\mathbf{y}}[g(\mathbf{y})]
\end{align}

But I am not sure if this is correct...

Could someone help me proving this by using some basic principles and properties? Also, are there any conditions/constraints over the functions so that the proposed equality holds?

Answer (score 1):

You have 
$$\min_{x,y} (f(x)+g(y)) \leq f(x)+g(y), \quad  \text{for all}\,\, x,y$$
which implies 
$$\min_{x,y} (f(x)+g(y)) \leq \min_x f(x)+ \min_y g(y)$$
On the other hand 
$$f(x)+g(y) \geq \min_x f(x) + \min_y g(y), \quad  \text{for all}\,\, x,y$$
therefore 
$$\min_{x,y} (f(x)+g(y)) \geq \min_x f(x)+ \min_y g(y)$$
So you have the equality.